# JxBrowser on Linux throws NoSuchMethodException: getWindow

Tags: linux, swing, jxbrowser

I am running some unit tests on a headless linux machine, but with Xvfb server started. 
The Browser gets created but seems that it has problems displaying it - see the exception.

```
03:53:39 INFO: OS name: Linux
03:53:39 INFO: JRE version: 1.8.0_31 64-bit
03:53:39 INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.4
03:53:39 INFO: JxBrowser type: HEAVYWEIGHT
```

My code looks similar to this

```
Frame frame = new JFrame("myFrame");
Browser browser = new Browser();
BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

On Windows environment works fine, but on Linux I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getWindow
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.NativeLinux.getWindowHandle(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.HeavyWeightWidget.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.HeavyWeightWidget.b(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.HeavyWeightWidget$d.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processHierarchyEvent(Component.java:6692)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6311)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.Component.createHierarchyEvents(Component.java:5541)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1443)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1439)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1622)
at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1042)
```

I have in my lib folder the following

- jxbrowser-6.4.jar
- jxbrowser-linux64-6.4.jar
- jxbrowser-mac-6.4.jar
- jxbrowser-win-6.4.jar

and in the build.xml of my tests this

```
<fileset dir="${myproject.dir}/lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    <exclude name="**/jxbrowser-mac*.jar"/>
    <exclude name="**/jxbrowser-win*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By default JxBrowser is run in the heavyweight rendering mode. In this mode we embed a native window into your Java application window and configure Chromium engine to render content into this native window using GPU. In order to embed a native window we need to get a handle of the top-level window in your Java application. The exception you see indicates that JxBrowser failed to get that handle. What Linux distribution you use?

You mentioned that you use JxBrowser in a headless Linux environment. In this case you don't need to create a BrowserView instance and embed it into a JFrame, so that should resolve the issue.

Also, you can use JxBrowser in the lightweight rendering mode that does not require a window handle:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);
```